# Update transient attribute in af:treeTable from bean

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an `af:treeTable` control in my ADF page that has an `af:selectBooleanCheckbox` column bound to a transient, Boolean VO attribute.  The purpose is to indicate which node(s) of the tree are selected.

When a user selects (or deselects) a node, I want that same change applied to all the descendant nodes in the tree hierarchy.

So, I have the `af:selectBooleanCheckbox` a value change listener to points to the code below.

```
    public void moTreeValueChangeListener(final ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
        
        final UIComponent cbCmp = valueChangeEvent.getComponent();
        Map<String, Object> clientAttributeMap = cbCmp.getAttributes();
        final String nodeKey = (String) clientAttributeMap.get("nodeKey");
        
        // Find all descendent nodes in tree table, using the invariant that child nodes will have node keys starting
        // with the ancestor's node key value.
        DCIteratorBinding itr = ADFUtils.findIterator("AddSupplyModelHierVO1Iterator");
        ViewObjectImpl vo = (ViewObjectImpl) itr.getViewObject();
    
        final Consumer<Row> rowProcessor = new Consumer<Row>() {
        @Override
            public void accept(Row row) {
                String rowNodeKey = (String) row.getAttribute("NodeKey");
                if ( rowNodeKey.startsWith(nodeKey) ) {
                    // This is a child.  Set it to the ancestor's new value!
                    row.setAttribute("Selector", valueChangeEvent.getNewValue());
                }
            }    
        };
        
        // Process the rows, applying the change to each child
        // NOTE: developer -- make sure value change listener is not firing for each recursive change
        processRowSetHierarchy(vo, "ChildNodeVOA", rowProcessor);
        // Tell the UI control to update since it's been changed
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(JSFUtils.findComponentInRoot("tt1"));
    }
    
    /**
     * Traverses a hierarchical row set and applies a set of processing logic to each row
     * @param rowSet starting row set
     * @param childAccessorName name of attribute in row implementation that accesses child rows
     * @param rowProcessor logic to apply to each row
     */
    private void processRowSetHierarchy ( RowSet rowSet, String childAccessorName, Consumer<Row> rowProcessor ) {
        final RowSetIterator rit = rowSet.createRowSetIterator(null);
        rit.reset();
        while ( rit.hasNext() ) {
            final Row r = rit.next();
            rowProcessor.accept(r);  // process the node
            // Get child nodes
            final RowSet childRowSet = (RowSet) r.getAttribute(childAccessorName);
            // Process all descendent nodes, recursively
            processRowSetHierarchy(childRowSet, childAccessorName, rowProcessor);
        }
        rit.closeRowSetIterator();
    }
```

I know from logging messages that the code IS firing and is accessing the VO row objects and setting the `Selector` attribute (which is what the `af:selectBooleanCheckbox` is bound to appropriately.

But, when I run it, it just doesn't work.  Selecting or deselecting a node has no visible impact on the child nodes in the tree.

I feel like I am missing something fundamental here.  Can anyone offer insights?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that, the 'Child' VO's transient attribute created at EO level instead of at VO level .